# c++ - declaration is incompatible with (method) - pointers

Tags: c++, variables, pointers

I recently started playing around with c++, but for I don't understand what this means:

**I get this error:**

> declaration is incompatible with "`void
>   student_system::addStudent(<error-type> z)`" (declared at line 31)

and the same goes for removeStudent and editStudent

I copied over the "function()" from another stackoverflow post, which seems fine and added the header with no issues, but my own "student" methods don't seem to work, I do not understand why,

I also tried adding the pointers rather than the variable but that didn't work either ( and by pointer I mean " student *x ").

```
#include "database.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

class student_system
{   
private: 
    list<student> studList;

public:
    student_system();
    void addStudent(student x);
    void removeStudent(student y);
    void editStudent(student z);
    void findPos();
    void function(int a, int b, vector<int> *p);
};

student_system::student_system()
{
    //constructor
}

void student_system::addStudent(student x)               // <------------- LINE 31 
{
    studList.push_back(x);
}
void student_system::removeStudent(student y)
{
    /*studList.rem*/
}

void student_system::editStudent(student z)
{
    /*get{ return value; }
        set{  }*/

}

void student_system::findPos()
{

}

void student_system::function(int a, int b, vector<int> *p)
{

}



class student
{
private:
    string name, surname, ID;
    int sid;
public : 
    student::student(int sid, string n, string s, string id);
};

student::student(int sid, string n, string s, string id)
{
    (*this).sid = sid;
    (*this).name = n;
    (*this).surname = s;
    (*this).ID = id;    
}
```

Comment: @Mat thanks for edit :p

Comment: `(*this).` could be written as `this->` and for the student constructor this is only required for `sid` - perhaps change the parameter. In addition use `const`. and references  i.e. `AddStudent(const& student s)`

Comment: `student` isn't defined when you try to use it in line 31. That can't work.

Comment: @EdHeal thanks for the tips, it is really appreciated (got any refs. to more 'tip' sites :p)

Comment: @KGCybeX - You could use ESA coding standard - http://www.esa.int/TEC/Software_engineering_and_standardisation/TECRFBUXBQE_0.html - This has lots of tips in it

Comment: @EdHeal this could also work if I create a new cpp file, add the "student" class in there, and #include that (i read in the c++ tut book it is not recommended to #include the cpp file, but rather the .h file)

Comment: Bung the class declaration (i.e. `class xxx {....};` with include guards) into the header file xxx.h. Put the definitions (i.e. `xxx:methoda(..)`) into xxx.cpp file. Look up header guards. Look up forward declarations as well. Something for you to do this new years day (if your hangover can stand it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this bit of code

```
class student
{
private:
    string name, surname, ID;
    int sid;
public : 
    student::student(int sid, string n, string s, string id);
};
```

Just after the

```
#include <vector>
```

So that `student_system` and its definitions know about it

Answer (score 1):

<s>Add `class student;` above your `student_system` class definition.</s>

**Edit**

Using forward declarations we can only *declare* methods in which we can use incomplete type not *define*. So, my first answer was wrong, but the following code will work.

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

// Forward Declaration
class student;

// ================================
//      Class student_system
// ================================
class student_system
{
private:
    list<student> studList;

public:
    student_system();
    void addStudent(student x);
    void removeStudent(student y);
    void editStudent(student z);
    void findPos();
    void function(int a, int b, vector<int> *p);
};


// ================================
//          Class student
// ================================
class student
{
private:
    string name, surname, ID;
    int sid;
public :
    student(int sid, string n, string s, string id);
};

// ================================
//     Definition of methods
// ================================

student::student(int sid, string n, string s, string id)
{
    (*this).sid = sid;
    (*this).name = n;
    (*this).surname = s;
    (*this).ID = id;
}

student_system::student_system()
{
    //constructor
}

void student_system::addStudent(student x)
{
    studList.push_back(x);
}
void student_system::removeStudent(student y)
{
    /*studList.rem*/
}

void student_system::editStudent(student z)
{
    /*get{ return value; }
        set{  }*/

}

void student_system::findPos()
{

}

void student_system::function(int a, int b, vector<int> *p)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Please simplify a problem down to its basest elements before posting.

2) Please don't post code that relies on non-provided includes or implicit "using" statements or the like

3) "student" should be declared before student_system. The fact that you're not getting more errors surprises me, but maybe you're doing something unseen in database.h

Comment: thanks, will keep that in mind for my next question (p.s. which might be soon)

Comment: These should be comments.